# How to make a caesar cipher work with input that has spaces in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

```
x = input('Please Enter a Sentence: ')
y = input('Please Enter a Number: ')
y = int(y)
g = list(x)
j = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
limit = 25
for e in g:
    q = j.index(e)
    if (q+y) > 25:   
        oman = (q+y) % 26
        newg = j[oman]
        print(newg, end="")
    elif (q+y) <= 25:
        newg = j[q+y]
        print(newg, end="")
```

I have to write a Caesar cipher for homework in python. (A caesar cipher shifts letters in phrase in order to decipher something.)

My program is supposed to take a sentence as and a number as input and shift each letter in the sentence by the input number. It works for phrases with no spaces, but I need it to work with spaces. Also, the program does not need to account for punctuation.

If anyone could give me some pointers on how to do this that would be very helpful.

I tried putting a space item in the alphabet variable but then the shift is off.

Comment: There are *thousands* of Cesar cipher questions here on Stack Overflow. None of those helped you with your problem?

Comment: `j.index(' ')` would throw an exception; do you already know how to handle exceptions? You could catch the exception here and just print the character without translation.

Comment: The only characters that you want to shift in the original sentence are alphabetic characters, correct?

Comment: How about "if e == ' ':" and then just continue?

Comment: You know, you don't need to check for the size of `q+y` if you always use `(q+y) % 26` in the index for `j`. So always just `newg = j[(q+y) % 26]`

Comment: related: [Caesar Cipher Function in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8886947/4279) -- the accepted answer works with spaces as is (it leaves them along).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code a bit, made it more general, and I tried to pick good descriptive names for the variables. You can now use a different list for `ceasar` - anything that is not in it will go through exactly the same.

On a related note, if you like cryptography, you can read the [NSA's old cryptanalysis manuals](http://www.nsa.gov/public_info/declass/military_cryptanalysis.shtml).

There's a lot of interesting information about ciphers in there, and the information about letter frequency analysis would allow you write a program that breaks a Ceasar cipher without having to try all 25 shifts first!

```
sentence = input('Please Enter a Sentence: ')
number   = input('Please Enter a Number: ')

shift   = int(number)
letters = list(sentence)
cipher  = '' 

ceasar = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

for letter in letters:
    if letter in ceasar:
        oldindex = ceasar.index(letter)
        newindex = (oldindex + shift) % len(ceasar)
        newletter = ceasar[newindex]
    else:
        newletter = letter

    print(letter, end="")
    cipher += newletter
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
def Cesar(input_string,key):
    new_string=""
    for i in range(len(input_string)):
       if input_string[i].isalpha():
           curr_char=input_string[i].lower()
           #do your shifting to curr_char with key and append to a new string.
       elif input_string[i]==' ':
           new_string+=' '
    return new_string
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much conceived an algorithm for actually using the Caser key and encrypting a a message so I'll just mention how to ensure the program doesn't leave out a space and ignores punctuation as you asked.

```
 encrypt=str(input("Enter a message"))
 b=""
    for i in encrypt:
     if i==chr(32):
         b+=i
     #32 is the ASCII number for a space(" "), chr is a function which converts a character to its ASCII number
     #after carry on with the actual algorithm to encrypt letters
```

To ignore the punctuation, you'll probably need to do something like this:

```
if i in ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"):
```

after the above, then carry out your execution of the code, that way the program will only deal with letters from a-z and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to store a list with the alphabet... (also handling Spanish chars)

```
def cesar(text, key):
    if key == 0:
        return text
    else:
        text = text.replace("á", chr(97)).replace("é", "e").replace("í", "i").replace("ó", "o").replace("ú", "u")\
        .replace("Á", "A").replace("É", "E").replace("Í", "I").replace("Ó", "O").replace("Ú", "U")\
        .replace("ñ", "n").replace("Ñ", "N")
        cipher = ""
        for x in range(len(text)):
            if text[x].isalpha():  # only shifting letters
                if text[x].islower():  # lowercase
                    cipher += chr((ord(text[x]) - 97 + key) % 26 + 97)
                else:  # uppercase
                    cipher += chr((ord(text[x]) - 65 + key) % 26 + 65)
            else:
                cipher += text[x]
        return cipher
```

The function `ord(char)` gives you a number for the character (A-Z is 65-..., a-z is 97-...), and the function `chr(int)` gives you a character for the number (the reverse from the other one).