# Making a unique extension id and key for Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension I made, but based it on some example found online.  Its not in a crx file.  The extension ID is the one used in the example.  I would like to change it before I upload my extension to the chrome store.  My question is how do I change this?  Do I just manually change the letters in my manifest.json file?  Or does the extension id have to be generated from something because its in a fixed format?  Same for the key, can I just randomly change these two before I do anything else now that I'm ready?

```
{
  // Extension ID: rnldjzfmornpzlahmmmgbagdohdnhdic
  "key": "MIGfMA3GCSqGSIb3DFEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaZhSpDCE9RCocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "Name of extension",
...
```

Answer (score 51):

Note that extension signing consists of two "keys":

- The private key file, `.pem`, that is used to sign CRX files and must remain the same for future updates.
- The resulting public key in the manifest - can't be used to sign future updates (used to verify the signature instead), but can be used to force a particular ID **for unpacked extensions** since the ID is derived as a hash of the public key. (For those curious, if `key` is not present an unpacked extension falls back to [hashing the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058672/934239)).

You have 2 options:

1. Let Google handle it.

   Remove the `key` field from the manifest completely; then submit it to the store.

   CWS will generate a new keypair for your extension (and, consequently, a new ID), which will be preserved between updates. If you need to maintain the ID for your development version (not always a good idea, as Chrome will get confused with autoupdates, but a good idea during `storage.sync` testing), you can extract the new public `key` from your Developer Dashboard using "More info" link on your item.

   However, there is no way to get the `.pem` key from CWS. You are forever locked in CWS as auto-update source. That shouldn't matter though as Chrome disallows extension installs from elsewhere.
2. Retain control of the private key.

   **Note: this apporoach may be deprecated by now, and there's not much practical reason to use it.**

   You can generate a CRX file of your extension from `chrome://extensions` using "Pack extension" function.

   If you don't provide an existing `.pem` file, Chrome will generate a new keypair (and thus, ID) for your extension.

   Guard the resulting `.pem` key <del>with your life</del> carefully. It can be used to impersonate you as a developer when it comes to updates.

   Then, when you submit the extension to CWS, [include the `.pem` in the archive's root as `key.pem`](http://web.archive.org/web/20180114092240/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging#upload) (**Note:** removed from documentation; links to an archived version). This instructs CWS to use it instead of generating a new keypair. Note that you have to provide your private key to Google, since it modifies the extensions before signing.

   Since the ID is a hash of a (randomly-generated) public key, there is a *tiny* chance of collision with an existing extension. If that happens, just re-generate the `.pem` file for a different one.

In either case: do not include the `key` field in the manifest when uploading, or CWS may reject it.

---

Also, do not hardcode the extension ID in your extension anywhere. It's accessible using one of those functions:

```js
chrome.runtime.getManifest().id // gives "youridehere"
chrome.runtime.getURL("something") // gives "chrome-extension://youridhere/something"
```

And in CSS files, you can use `__MSG_@@extension_id__` as a macro:

```css
background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/background.png');
```

Comment: "no way to get the .pem key from CWS" answered my question.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: This helped me use the unique id during development and update. Thanks.

Comment: One practical reason to set your own id is if you want to load your unpublished extension into an electron app. This is done using session.defaultSession.loadExtension(path_to_extension), and path_to_extension contains the extendion id. If you install an unpacked extension without setting your own id, this will be random.

Answer (score 34):

You can create you own key and extension ID for the manifest:

> openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -out key.pem
>
> Key:
>
> openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -outform DER | openssl base64 -A
>
> Extension ID:
>
> openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -outform DER | shasum -a 256 | head
> -c32 | tr 0-9a-f a-p

Comment: if your system doesn't have shasum but does have xxd you can use `openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | xxd -p` instead of `shasum -a 256`

Comment: any ideas how to run Extension ID command for Windows?