# Constant chrome extension ID in dev mode

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension. Cause of i'm in China and the project works in LAN, I cant upload the extension to google store. I load my extension as a folder in chrome dev mode and I found that, different people have different extension ID. I want to have one ID in all different chrome browsers so that my web app can invoke it.

I'm working in LAN and can't upload extention to google store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has already been asked before. You can either add the key in yourself by generating your own and adding it to your manifest.

Or you can upload it to the store, but it sounds like you can't do that.

So adding a key to your manifest sounds like your solution.

[Making a unique extension id and key for Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317779/making-a-unique-extension-id-and-key-for-chrome-extension)

[Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development)

[Keep chrome extension id same during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422195/keep-chrome-extension-id-same-during-development)