# Send message to Chrome App from Web Page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, messaging

**app.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("Message Recived");        
  });
```

**Page.html**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("From WebPage", { openUrlInEditor: "http://localhost:54854/MainPage.html" },
          function (response) {             

          });
```

**manifest.json**

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

But still I cant send message from Web Page to Chrome APP.
Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

Kindly Help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` for sending an *external* message is not an arbitrary ID, but the ID of the extension/app that will receive the message.

For published apps, the ID is fixed at the moment you first submit it to the store.

For unpacked apps, the ID is determined by the `"key"` field in the manifest, if any, or [by the path to the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053434/how-is-the-chrome-extension-id-of-an-unpacked-extension-generated). It may be useful to [fix the ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development), so that it does not change from computer to computer.

Comment: Okay I got the web page message to Chrome APP. but can I do it vice versa? that is send message from Chrome APP to Web Page?

Comment: You can't initiate it from the app. You can only reply to messages with `sendResponse` or open a Port for 2-directional communication with `connect()`, but either has to be initiated by the page.

Comment: Well I guess I can then Communicate using the this flow : Chrome APP => Chrome Extension => My WebPage? :P

Comment: That's overkill. Why not open a Port immediately by the page, and then message from app using the port as required?

Comment: Well I will have to call Web Page function on hardware event from Chrome APP

Comment: And that's exactly why I'm suggesting Ports. Once established from web page side, you can send a message from app upon event, repeatedly.