# How stable is a chrome extension ID?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I release an extension in the Chrome webstore, can I be sure that everyone who downloads and installs this extension has the same app ID (forever)?

Comment: yes. why you doubt?

Comment: I changed the name of the directory the app was in and it immediately changed the id so I was not sure which circumstances affect the id. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The id of an unpacked Chrome extension changes according to the directory name unless you specify a `"key"` in the manifest.json. (see [manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) and [key](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key))

Once published in the Chrome Web Store it will be assigned an id and a key that will not change.

Comment: Relevant: [How is the Chrome Extension ID of an unpacked extension generated?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058672/934239)

Comment: More relevant questions: [Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development) and [How to change chrome packaged app id Or Why do we need key field in the manifest.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497781/how-to-change-chrome-packaged-app-id-or-why-do-we-need-key-field-in-the-manifest)