# Reverse searching Chrome extensions by id

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Today, I have found that something had changed registry values for Chrome policy in my laptop. 
It is in 'ExtensionInstallWhitelist' which as the name suggests whitelists chrome extensions.

So, Now I have three extension ids, but don't know how they got there. I googled them and found that one of them belongs to an old malware. But remaining are getting no results.

Is there any way to search for extensions using their ids, or does extension ids change with time and machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply goto this URL: `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/TEXT/ID_HERE`. The `TEXT` part doesn't matter, it will redirect automatically.

However, note that if the extension is installed locally, or is private, it will not appear on the webstore. Locally installed extensions will have an orange icon in the bottom-right of their logo on the `chrome://extensions` page.

See also: [How is the Chrome Extension ID of an unpacked extension generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053434/how-is-the-chrome-extension-id-of-an-unpacked-extension-generated)

Comment: in my situation that's not good enough because i can't copy&paste the extension id, i can only see the extension id from here (without copypasting it): https://i.imgur.com/nqI0J51.png

Comment: @hanshenrik I think if you right click on that tab and copy path to the file you would get the ID.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative, if it is an extension you already have installed:

- got to `chrome://extensions`
- enable "developer mode"
- ctrl+f and write the id (or just the first 3-4 characters of the id)

[image]