# Python - Characters Not Decrypting Correctly

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I have been working on a program which will take a plaintext file, encrypt the message and then decrypt the message. When I decrypt the message, the commas within the text file are replaced with different ASCII characters. Does anybody have a solution or can help me on the problem?

Please note: I have contained my code within a pastebin due to the fact it is quite long and I don't know what parts I could post that specify the problem. Thank you!

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/fym8DaP7)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for an intro to asking questions that will likely receive answers, and for a badge :) .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing. Your code must be on Stack Overflow and not hidden behind some link. Please [edit] your question to include the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you need to change your algorithm rather than merely fix a bug in your implementation.  Your encryption algorithm appears to change only characters for which the ASCII value plus the `finalNumber` exceeds 126.  In general, this means you can't reliably tell whether a letter was encrypted or not.  For example, in `encrypt`, this block

```
added = finalNumber + valLetter
if added > 126:
    subtracted = added - 94
    encrypted += chr(subtracted)
else:
    encrypted += chr(valLetter)
```

will make some letters overlap.  Suppose `finalNumber` is `30`.  To encrypt `'a'`, which is ASCII 97, `added=127`.  Thus `subtracted=33`, and `'!'` will be written to `encrypted`.  However, when you encrypt a `'!'` itself, `added`=`33+30`=`63`, which is not greater than `126`, so the `'!'` will be copied through.  When you try to decrypt, you won't be able to tell whether a `'!'` in the encrypted text should be decrypted to an `'a'` or a `'!'`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947) is about building a Caesar cipher in Python, which appears to be what you are trying to do.  I recommend starting there.  Good luck!

(note: not tested; this answer is based on reading the source only.)