# How do I correctly replace characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming in general, and couldn't figure out how to replace multiple characters in a string. Using the `string.replace("x", "y")` function, I tried to make a simple encoder:

```
phrase = "abcdef"
phrase.replace("a", "b")
phrase.replace("b", "c")
phrase.replace("c", "d")
phrase.replace("d", "e")
phrase.replace("e", "f")
phrase.replace("f", "g")

print(phrase)
```

I was expecting the output to be:

`"bcdefg"`

but instead got

`"abcdef"`

This was best I could come up with and it does not work. I looked around other questions and the answers were too confusing. Please help and explain what i am doing wrong.

Comment: `phrase =phrase.replace("f", "g").replace("e", "f").replace("d", "e").replace("c", "d").replace("b", "c").replace("a", "b")`

Comment: "it does not work" is not specific enough. Are you getting error messages? Or unexpected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python 3 you can use `str.maketrans` and `str.translate` (links below) - for python 2 you can find them inside the `string` module:

```
# from string import maketrans, translate # python 2, in python 3 they are on str

trans = str.maketrans("abcdef","bcdefg")

phrase = "abcdef"

print(str.translate(phrase, trans)) # outputs: bcdefg
```

See

- [str.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)
- [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the string with the output of `phrase.replace()`. Since `phrase` is a string, it does not get updated as strings are immutable. You also have to change the order of your replacements or you get `gggggg` as a result:

```
phrase = "abcdef"
phrase = phrase.replace("f", "g")
phrase = phrase.replace("e", "f")
phrase = phrase.replace("d", "e")
phrase = phrase.replace("c", "d")
phrase = phrase.replace("b", "c")
phrase = phrase.replace("a", "b")

print(phrase)
```

```
bcdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

the replace function returns a **new** string that is the copy of the previous one with the characters replaced, so your code should be, as @depperm mentioned:

```
phrase = phrase.replace("f", "g").replace("e", "f").replace("d", "e").replace("c", "d").replace("b", "c").replace("a", "b")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just made a quick search for you and found this [Change each character in string to the next character in alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643778/change-each-character-in-string-to-the-next-character-in-alphabet)

where @dawg put this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

s='abcxyz'
ns=''
for c in s:
    if c in letters:
        ns=ns+letters[(letters.index(c)+1)%len(letters)]
    else:
        ns+=c
```

Tested it and worked fine, *ns* value is 'bcdyza'

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to learn python a great tool to use in the python repl. In this case there's nothing wrong with the replace method, it's your logic that's incorrect. So let's see what's going on in the repl.

```
>>> phrase = "abcdef"
>>> phrase.replace("a", "b")
'bbcdef'
>>> phrase.replace("b", "c")
'accdef'
>>> phrase.replace("c", "d")
'abddef'
>>> phrase.replace("d", "e")
'abceef'
>>> phrase.replace("e", "f")
'abcdff'
>>> phrase.replace("f", "g")
```

The correct algorithm for this kind of caesar cipher would be something like.

```
s = ''
for i in range(len(phrase)):
   s += chr(ord(phrase[i])+1)
```

Hope this helps.