# Replace each letter in a last name by the consecutive letter in the alphabet

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to replace each letter in a last name by the consecutive letter in the alphabet? I need this script as a masking tool.

Logic for last name: (a change to b, b change to c, ...., z change to a)

Example: John Doe will become John Epf

Input File: `names.txt`

```
John yi
kary Strong
Joe Piazza
So  man
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as defined in your question can be solved as follows:

```
parts = name.split()
parts[1]=''.join([chr((ord(c) - 65 + 1) % 26 + 65)
                  if ord(c) < 91 else
                  chr((ord(c) - 97 + 1) % 26 + 97)
                  for c in parts[1]])
' '.join(parts)
```

Here, I define the last name as the second word of the string, this of course is a strong assumption, but improving on this is not the main problem in the question.

Shifting the characters is done inside a list comprehension, where each character is processed separately, and first converted to its ASCII code using `ord`. The ASCII codes of upper case letters are 65-90 (`A`-`Z`), and the ASCII codes of lowercase letters are 97-122 (`a`-`z`). Therefore, a condition `ord(c) < 91` is used to separate the cases. Then, in each case, the ASCII code is converted to a value in the range 0-25, shifted (in the example, incremented by 1), and modulo operation `% 26` is used to convert shifted `z` back into `a`. The resulting value is then converted back to the proper range for the letter ASCII codes.

Comment: Does this do z to a?

Comment: No, but this should, for lower and upper case.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @ And - Your explanation is really helpful. Thank You So Much! I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Caesar's cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Take a look at how it's done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895517/6664393

You'll have change it a little to allow uppercase characters as well:

```
def caesar(plaintext, shift):
    alphabet_lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    alphabet_upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    alphabet = alphabet_lower + alphabet_upper
    shifted_alphabet_lower = alphabet_lower[shift:] + alphabet_lower[:shift]
    shifted_alphabet_upper = alphabet_upper[shift:] + alphabet_upper[:shift]
    shifted_alphabet = shifted_alphabet_lower + shifted_alphabet_upper
    table = string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
return plaintext.translate(table)
```

use `shift = 1` to shift by one.