# Ascii decoding function in Python, what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, ascii

I have this function that decodes a letter by a given key

```
def decode_char(n, key):
    adj = ord('a') if n.islower() else ord('A') 
    return chr(adj + (ord(n)-adj-int(key))%26)
```

I am trying to get this to work, so a word is decoded

```
def decode_block(word,key):
    letters = list(word)
    keys = list(key)
    decoded = []
    for letter, digit in zip(letters, keys):
        decoded.append(decode_char(letter, digit))
    return "".join(decoded)
```

when I input this

```
print(decode_char('bddffhhj', '12121212'))
```

I get this error message

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 8 found
```

I need to get

```
abcdefgh
```

I can't figure out why the `ord(n)` in `decode_char` isn't recieveing a character?

I have split the word into a list? and zipped these to the digits of the key?

Just a student so please don't go ham

Anyone?

Comment: What exactly does "it doesn't work" mean? The expected output and description of what the code does would help a lot here. EDIT: and avoid saying "it doesn't work" in future questions ;)

Comment: @GerryHernandez Edited above

Comment: Incase you are looking for:  [Caesar Cipher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947/caesar-cipher-function-in-python)

Comment: @Bhansa This is for an assignment I have that everything has to be made from scratch, not allowed certain functions such as cipher etc.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to understand how you are using your code_block and keys working together. Try different scenarios , work with examples.

Comment: You've received two answers. Did any of those answers answer your question? If not, you can post your own answer. If they did, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `decode_char`. It should be almost the same as `code_char`, except for subtracting the `key` integer instead of adding it. Here's a repaired version.

```
def decode_char(n, key):
    adj = ord('a') if n.islower() else ord('A') 
    return chr(adj + (ord(n)-adj-int(key))%26)
```

---

I don't understand why you have `encrypt` and `code_block`. You can get rid of `encrypt` and rename `code_block` to `encrypt`. The same goes for `decrypt` / `decode_block`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def code_char(c, key):
    return chr(ord(c)+key%26)
code_char('a',3)

def decode_char(c,key):
    return chr(ord(c)-key%26)
decode_char('d',3)
```

**Sample Example**

```
txt = "This is a secret message!!"

#encoding
lista = []
for i in txt:
    lista.append(code_char(i,3))
print ''.join(lista)

encoded = ''.join(lista)

lista = []
#decoding
for i in encoded:
    lista.append(decode_char(i,3))
print ''.join(lista)

decoded = ''.join(lista)
```

**Output**:

```
Wklv#lv#d#vhfuhw#phvvdjh$$
This is a secret message!!
```

Comment: While your code is simpler than the OP's your encoding / decoding process is rather different to what the OP is doing. Their algorithm only maps letter to letters of the same case and leaves other chars unchanged.

Comment: Hmm, I have doubts about his encoding algorithm. I'll update.