# Caesar Cipher in Python (unexpected error)

Tags: python, encryption

I have to encrypt a user-provided plaintext using Caesar Cipher. Converting each plaintext character to its ASCII (integer) value  and store in a list.
I have done like this

```
print("This program uses a Caesar Cipher to encrypt a plaintext message using the encryption key you provide.")
plaintext = input("Enter the message to be encrypted:")
plaintext = plaintext.upper()
n = eval(input("Enter an integer for an encrytion key:"))
ascii_list = []

# encipher
ciphertext = ""
for x in range(len(plaintext)):
    ascii_list[x] = plaintext (ascii_list) + n %26
    print()
```

But error appears as like this:

```
   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I want the result to come out:

```
This program uses a Caesar Cipher to encrypt a plaintext message using the encryption key you provide.
Enter the message to be encrypted: Boiler Up Baby!
Enter an integer for an encrytion key: 1868
The fully encoded message is: CWOTFZ&]QCHICa'
```

I have tried so many different ways but the result does not come out.

Comment: What do you expect `plaintext (ascii_list)` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the initial characters to numbers, add the key to them and then parse them back to characters.

In your code `ascii_list[x]` must be changed to `ascii_list.append()` because you are referencing an index that does not exist. Also `plaintext` is not a function that you can call, it is just your initial message in uppercase.

You can do this:

```
for x in range(len(plaintext)):
    ascii_list.append(chr(ord(plaintext[x]) + n))
print(ascii_list)
```

**Note:**
The input/output (in:`Boiler Up Baby!`, out:`CWOTFZ&]QCHICa'`) you provided is not typical Caesar cipher as some of the letters turn into symbols and also the symbols are encoded as well. Using this solution will only shift the keys up, meaning that for example `Z` will never become `A`. If you need proper Caesar cipher solution you might want to look at this question: [Caesar Cipher Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947/caesar-cipher-function-in-python)