# Shift letters by a certain value in python

Tags: python

I had a coded text file that was coded by simple letter shifting. I have now gotten the information from it into two lists. In this format:

```
list_1 =['fjsir', 'vnjk', 'eioafnvjf', 'einbvfbj']
list_2 =[3,4,7,1]
```

The second list is by how many places in the alphabet should it move over. For eg. if index 0 in list one had `'fjsir'` and it's corresponding index in `list_2` is 3 then it would decode to `'cfpeo'`. I'm not sure how I would match these in python.

Comment: It may seem laborious, but have you tried converting the letters to numbers, subtracting the value from list 2, then converting back to letters?

Comment: aka [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) - see also: [Caesar Cipher Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947/caesar-cipher-function-in-python)

Answer (score 14):

To shift elements to the left:

```
chr(ord(char) - n)
```

Which uses [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#ord) to get an integer representation of `char`, and substracts `n` from this number. It then uses [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#chr) to convert it back to a character.

The function could look like this:

```
def shift(s, n):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(char) - n) for char in s)
```

Which can get called nicely with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
list_1 =['fjsir', 'vnjk', 'eioafnvjf', 'einbvfbj']
list_2 =[3,4,7,1]

for x, y in zip(list_1, list_2):
    print(shift(x, y))
```

And gives back the decodings:

```
cgpfo
rjfg
^bhZ_goc_
dhmaueai
```

Additionally, if you only want decodings to only consist of letters from the English alphabet, you can use a modulus function `%` instead:

```
 def shift(s, n):
     return ''.join(chr((ord(char) - 97 - n) % 26 + 97) for char in s)
```

Which gives back decodings with only letters:

```
cgpfo
rjfg
xbhtygocy
dhmaueai
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution:

```
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
list_1 = ['fjsir', 'vnjk', 'eioafnvjf', 'einbvfbj']
list_2 = [3,4,7,1]
final_list = []
for index,original_word in enumerate(list_1):
    new_word = ''
    for letter in original_word:
        if letter in alphabets:
            index_val = alphabets.index(letter) - list_2[index]
            new_word += alphabets[index_val]
    final_list.append(new_word)
print final_list
```

Output:
['cgpfo', 'rjfg', 'xbhtygocy', 'dhmaueai']

Comment: why `alpha` and this much loops are using while `chr(), ord() and zip `are available in python ?

Comment: I wanted to avoid the inbuilt functions to make it simple to understand.

Comment: then it will take more time. That's not a good practice. and It doesn't seems simple any more/

Comment: Its just one of the many ways to solve the problem, indeed it's not efficient but its platform-independent code.

Comment: @OmiHarjani - if your goal is to make simple-to-understand code, I'd suggest using more descriptive variables: "original_word" instead of "i", "new_word" instead of "letter", "character" instead of "j", "shifted_index" instead of "index_val", etc. Also the `if list_2[index]` is unnecessary here - it's purely an optimization.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thank You I shall optimize the code accordingly :)

Comment: This also has the nice property that you don't have to worry about handling the modulus - the negative index into `alphabets` does it for you.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Yes and keeps the code simple for a noobie like me Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert characters to number with `ord()` and convert numbers to characters with `chr()`. A shift function may look like:

```
def shift_string(inString, inOffset):
    return "".join([chr(ord(x) + inOffset) for x in inString])
```

Accessing array elements from list is left to the reader. ;)

**Note:** This simple version will probably produce unwanted characters. You may simply use a modulo function to remain in the ASCII range.

```
def shift_string(inString, inOffset):
    return "".join([chr(((ord(x) - ord(' ') + inOffset) % 95) + ord(' ')) for x in inString])
```

If your set of valid characters is more complex (e.g. letters), you should write a special function for the character transformation.

Comment: I think we have to subtract the offset instead of adding it.

Comment: And probably use a modulus - it's _letter_ shifting, after all, not _ascii_ shifting.

Comment: @RoadRunner: Yes, you can handle this by calling the function with the negative of the offset: `shift_string('fjsir', -3)` instead of `shift_string('fjsir', 3)`.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks: I thought about that, too. But it's unclear what are the valid characters for output. If only letters are valid for instance, a simple modulus wouldn't be enough.