# Python code for alphabet after given number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input:

```
D
3
```

Output:

```
G
```

Explanation:
3rd element from D is G in alphabets

And how do you code if the input is x and 4 and I should get the output as b.
Help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shift letters by a certain value in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514673/shift-letters-by-a-certain-value-in-python)

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider utilizing the [modulo operator (`%`)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), [`str.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper), and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase


def shift_letter(c: str, n: int) -> str:
  if len(c) != 1:
    raise ValueError('c must be a single letter.')
  if not c.isalpha():
    raise ValueError('c must be a letter.')
  current_index = ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')
  new_index = (current_index + n) % 26
  new_c = ascii_lowercase[new_index]
  return new_c if c.islower() else new_c.upper()


def main() -> None:
  print(f"shift_letter('D', 3) = {shift_letter('D', 3)}")
  print(f"shift_letter('x', 4) = {shift_letter('x', 4)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

**Output:**

```
shift_letter('D', 3) = G
shift_letter('x', 4) = b
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have `ascii_lowercase` and `ascii_uppercase` in `string` module to use. Using the indexes from these strings and `%` operator you can shift the character:

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase


def shift_char(char: str, n):
    if char.isupper():
        idx = ascii_uppercase.index(char)
        return ascii_uppercase[(idx + n) % len(ascii_uppercase)]
    else:
        idx = ascii_lowercase.index(char)
        return ascii_lowercase[(idx + n) % len(ascii_lowercase)]


print(shift_char("D", 3))
print(shift_char("x", 4))
```

output:

```
G
b
```

Answer (score 0):

[ord](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord) and [chr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#chr) string methods are really useful for this problem.

`ord` gives you the Unicode code for a character:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> ord('b')
98
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> ord('B')
66
```

Given the code, `chr`, will give you the Unicode character

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

So to get the 3rd character from 'D', you could do

```
>>> code = ord('D') + 3
>>> char = chr(code)
>>> print(char)
G
```

or, as a one-liner

```
>>> print(chr(ord('D')+3))
G
```