# Shifting all the alphabets of a string by a certain step

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops, indexing

- input: `['baNaNa', 7]`       # string and step size
- required output : `'utGtGt'` # every character of string shifted backwards by step size

```
import ast  
in_string = input()  
lis = ast.literal_eval(in_string)  
st = lis[0]  
step = lis[1]  
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  
password = ''  
for letter in st:  
    if letter in alphabets:  
        index_val = alphabets.index(letter) - (step)  
        password += alphabets[index_val]  

print(password)
```

Output i am getting is 'utgtgt'. I want 'utGtGt'. Help on this would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: I have 'uttt' when i try

Comment: What should `'A'` become? Or any of `abcdef`?

Comment: since baNaNa should return utGtGt i gues `a` would become `t`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caesar Cipher Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886947/caesar-cipher-function-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

The string module has methods to [create a transformation dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and a [translate method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to do exactly what you want:

```
st = "baNaNa"
step = 7
alphabets = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alph2 = alphabets.upper() 

# lower case translation table
t = str.maketrans(alphabets, alphabets[-step:]+alphabets[:-step])

# upper case translation table
t2 = str.maketrans(alph2, alph2[-step:]+alph2[:-step])

# merge both translation tables
t.update(t2)

print(st.translate(t))
```

Output:

```
utGtGt
```

You give it the original string and an equal long string to map letters to and apply that dictionary using `str.translate(dictionary)`.

The sliced strings equate to:

```
print(alphabets)
print(alphabets[-step:]+alphabets[:-step])

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
tuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrs
```

which is what your `step` is for.

---

See [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) if you never saw string slicing in use.

Comment: Really neat! The answer given appears to shift only lower-case characters. How would one go about shifting upper-case characters as well? (e.g. `baNaNa` to `utGtGt`, rather than `utNtNt`)

Comment: @saha I thought thats clear - you apply the same thing for capital letters. I edited them in as well.

Answer (score 3):

by processing each charater and checking it's cardinal no and making calculation accordingly help you to reach the result

```
def func(string, size):
    if size%26==0:
        size=26
    else:
        size=size%26
    new_str = ''    
    for char in string:
        if char.isupper():
            if ord(char)-size<ord('A'):
                new_str+=chr(ord(char)-size+26)
            else:
                new_str+=chr(ord(char)-size)
        elif char.islower():
            if ord(char)-size<ord('a'):
                new_str+=chr(ord(char)-size+26)
            else:
                new_str+=chr(ord(char)-size)         
    return new_str


res =func('baNaNa', 7)   
print(res)

# output utGtGt
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution that makes use of the `%` modulo operator to shift letters backwards.

It basically collects all of the letters in a reverse index lookup dictionary, so looking up letter positions is `O(1)` instead of using `list.index()`, which is linear `O(N)` lookups.

Then it goes through each letter and calculates the shift value from the letter index e.g. for the letter `a` with a shift value of `7`, the calculation will be `(0 - 7) % 26`, which will give `19`, the position of `u`.

Then once you have this shift value, convert it to uppercase or lowercase depending on the case of the *original* letter.

At the end we just `str.join()` the result list into one string. This is more efficient than doing `+=` to join strings.

**Demo:**

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def letter_backwards_shift(word, shift):
    letter_lookups = {letter: idx for idx, letter in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}
    alphabet = list(letter_lookups)

    result = []
    for letter in word:
        idx = letter_lookups[letter.lower()]
        shifted_letter = alphabet[(idx - shift) % len(alphabet)]

        if letter.isupper():
            result.append(shifted_letter.upper())
        else:
            result.append(shifted_letter.lower())

    return ''.join(result)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> letter_backwards_shift('baNaNa', 7)
utGtGt
```

I would probably go with [@Patrick Artner's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153937/shifting-all-the-alphabets-of-a-string-by-a-certain-step/61154123#61154123) pythonic solution. I just showed the above implementation as a learning exercise :-).